# C# count each element in string array

Tags: c#

I have file of such data:

- 2016-07-01 - this is data
- 39
- 40
- 36
- 37
- 40
- 37

I want to count each elements in my array. For example: 10, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2. How do that?

```
        string FilePath = @"path";
        int counteachelement = 0;
        string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(FilePath);
        string[] integerStrings = fileContent.Split(new char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        for (int n = 0; n < integerStrings.Length; n++)
        {
           counteachelement = integerStrings.GetLength(n);
           Console.Write(counteachelement + "\n");
        }
```

Comment: `Array.GetLength` returns the  number of elements in the specified dimension. You have a `string[]` with only one dimension so this is useless. You can use `integerStrings.Length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I have modified your code to get the count of each element inside the for loop that you are using-

```
        string FilePath = @"path";
        int counteachelement = 0;
        string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(FilePath);
        string[] integerStrings = fileContent.Split(new char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        int count = 0;
        for (int n = 0; n < integerStrings.Length; n++)
        {
            count = integerStrings[n].Length;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

how about

```
List<int> Result = integerStrings.Select(x => x.Length).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `File.ReadLines()` to avoid holding all the lines in memory at once, and then simply use `Enumerable.Select()` to pick out the length of each line. (This assumes that you are not ignoring or do not have any blank lines):

```
var lengths = File.ReadLines(FilePath).Select(s => s.Length);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", lengths));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript:

```js
 
var arr=["39","9","139"];
var temp="";
for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
 temp += (arr[i].length) + ", ";
alert("Lenght element array: " +temp.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Linq` to do this

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();

list.Add("39");
list.Add("40");
list.Add("36");
list.Add("37");
list.Add("40");
list.Add("37");
list.Add("39");

var output = list.Select(i => i.Length);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ",output));
//"2 2 2 2 2 2 2"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] contents = File.ReadAllLines(@"myfile.txt");
foreach(var line in contents)
{
  line.Length // this is your string length per line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do,

```
var str = "2016-07-01 - this is data,39,40,36,37,40,37,";
var Result = str.Split(',').Select(p => p.Count()).ToList();
```

Note: I am considering your input as comma separated values.